# Grails is throwing a cannot be null error on a field without that limitation

Tags: mysql, grails, grails-orm, triggers

Using GRAILs and MySQL to build my application.

I have a MySQL BEFORE INSERT trigger that works very well:

```
USE `scheduler`;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `devices_BINS` BEFORE INSERT ON `devices` FOR EACH ROW
begin
    If new.device_type = 'DU' THEN
        Select IFNULL(max(external_id), '00-000') into @oldMc from `devices` where device_type = 'DU';
        SET @IntMc = CAST(Concat(left(@oldMc,2), right(@oldMc,3)) as unsigned);
        SET @IntMc=@IntMc+1;
        set @newMC = LPAD(CAST(@IntMc as CHAR(10)), 5, 0);
        set new.external_id = CONCAT(left(@newMC, 2),'-',right(@newMC, 3));
    elseiF new.device_type = 'ATM' THEN
        set new.external_id = new.serial_number;
    END IF;     
end
```

When I implement the structure in a GRAILS domain, and try to create an entry i get:

```
Property [external_id] of class [class cms.Devices] cannot be null
```

from the objects Errors property.

Here is the odd thing:  external_id is allowed to be null in the DB (even has Null as a default value); and the only constraint in the domain is external_id(blank:true).  BTW: changing this seems to have no effect.

Any thoughts why?  or how I can maybe just "Skip" the error in validation check of the controller?

here is the domain class

```
class Devices {
    String external_id
    String serial_number
    String model_type
    Device_Type device_type
    Status status
    String toString(){
        "$device_type - $external_id"
    }   

    enum Status {
        Tentative, Active, Offline, Terminated
    }

    enum Device_Type {
        DU, ATM
    }

    Locations locations

    static constraints = {
        device_type()
        model_type()
        serial_number(unique: true)
        status()
        external_id(blank:true)
    }

    static mapping = {
        version false
        id column: 'device_id'
        locations column:'location_id'
    }
}
```

Comment: by default properties on Grails domain classes are not nullable. Add nullable: true to your domain class and then do a grails clean. That should fix the issue.

Comment: Can you add the domain class? Look like you are using the actual column name in the constraints instead of the domain class property name. Generally, constraint should be `externalId blank: true, nullable: true`. Also note all properties are `nullable false` by default. You have to add `nullable true` constraint.

Comment: For educational purposes you can do a `.save(validate:false)` but I would advise against doing that.